# Getting undefined values in NVD3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to use nvd3 to plot some data. My data is a 2d array, the first position is the x value (which is a Date), and the second is my y value.

```
var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart()
            .x(function (d) { return d[0]; })
            .y(function (d) { return d[1]; })
```

When I zoom it until a value that I don't have data (for an example, I have monthly data and I zoomed between days) I got d as undefined. There is a way to interpolate the values to show something when I'm zoomed?

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThQGI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check in your complete code, you should have something like

```
d3.select('#my-chart svg')
  .datum(myData)
  .call(chart);
```

try to check if your `myData` have some `undefined` values

```
[..., [undefined, undefined], ...]
```